# Recommended mobile AR SDK/Platform for beginners

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform, augmented-reality

What would be the easiest to learn/use Augmented Reality SDK. Ideally, base ios functionality is be needed, cross platform with android is ideal but not required.

I have done cross platform OCR on xamarin before, however this was static and I do not think it would work the best for a live AR project. Assuming I know the language needed for the SDK, C#, Javascript, react native etc. I have looked at various AR kits but am unable to decide on one, ease of UI control is a reasonably important factor I cannot seem find much information about.

What was be the easiest/ideal SDK to use for a scenario such as scanning a QR code to bring up a list of continually changing content for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AR Foundation by Unity, as it is very versatile, works both on Android and iOS and I consider Unity quite easy to learn.

Just for QR codes and to bring content / models 3D, for this specific task, I think Vuforia is easier, just in my opinion.